# How to get all the array values from vue response

Tags: arrays, node.js, vue.js

How do i access the full course array
[image]

the code below gives me the first course array.

```
<div class="form-group"  v-show="school === 'SOSE'">
      <label for="course">Course</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="course" v-model="course">
        <option v-for="(result, index) in response" :value="result.course[0].initial">{{result.course[0].name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

if i use the index, course becomes undefined. How do i get values in both arrays.

Code for fetching data.

```
created() {
    axios.get(`https://${location.host}/admin/getSchool`)
      .then(resp => {
        this.response = resp.data;
        console.log(this.response);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.errors.push(err);
      })
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use two `v-for` here I used the `template` tag for it.

```
  <select class="form-control" name="course" v-model="course">
    <template v-for="result in response">
      <option v-for="course in result.course" :value="course.initial">{{course.name}}</option>
    </template>
  </select>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm; spent more than 3 hours on this. A heavy load of my head. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**nodejs**

try

```
result.forEach(function(item){
    console.log('initial: ' + item.initial);
    console.log('name: ' + item.name);
});
```

Hope it will be useful